# Calculus Critical Nums and Max/Min

Tags: calculus

Consider the line $y = 2x - 1$ and the point $P = (2,0)$.

(a) Write the formula for a function $d(x)$ that describes the distance between the point P and a point (x,y) on the line. You final answer should only involve the variable x. Then $d(x)$ = ...

(b) $d'(x)$ = ...

(c) The critical number is $x$ = ...

(d) The closest point on the line to $P$ is ( , ).

If someone could help me with setting up $d(x)$ I can do the rest of the issue. I'm having a hard time getting started.

Comment: You are being asked to find the distance between the following two points $(x,2x-1)$ and $(2,0)$

Answer (score 1):

The distance from the point $(2,0)$ to any other point $(x,y)$ is given by $$\sqrt{(x-2)^2 + (y-0)^2} = \sqrt{(x-2)^2 + y^2}.$$
Now since you only want to consider points on the line $y=2x-1$, plug in $2x-1$ for $y$:
$$\sqrt{(x-2)^2 + (2x-1)^2}.$$
You might want to simplify a bit, but that's your function $d(x)$.